# How to use linux keyboard layout in windows?

Tags: linux, windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I use a ISO keyboard (105 keys) and want to use the US american layout, which was designed for ANSI (104 keys) keyboards. There is one US Layout which fits perfectly on my ISO keyboard. But unfortunately that's a linux version.

LINK to the keyboard layout I want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:LinuxUSKeyboard.png

How do I get this layout in Windows 10?

Thanks in advance,
H.i.M

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339).

You can create the layout you want for yourself!

Comment: MSKLC supposedly does not work on Windows 10, though layouts created with it on Windows 7 will be usable on Windows 10.

Comment: I checked it a bit and search on the internet, and it seems to work fine with Windows 10. Did you have any problems using it on Windows 10?

Comment: More like I had trouble _installing_ it on Windows 10, but I don't remember what, exactly, the issue was, and when I binggoogleduckduckgoed to try to figure out what the problem was, the consensus, which included comments from MicroSofties, was that it didn't work/wasn't supported.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I could run and install MSKLC with "run as administrator" in Windows 10.

Comment: @H.i.M - If the given answer worked for you, you should ACCEPT the answer by clicking the checkmark. It marks the question as having been satisfactorily answered, and it gives the answerer some rep on the site.